# Which query performs better IF Exists (Query) vs IF( ResultCount > 0) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

A query that checks the existance of data

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM Persons 
    WHERE PName = 'John')
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'YES'
    END
```

A query that returns the result count and then compares:-

```
    IF((SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM Persons 
    WHERE PName = 'John') > 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'YES'
    END
```

In Persons table PName column is a nonclustered unique index

Comment: See the last section here: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `if exists`.  This can stop at the first matching row (if any).  The aggregation query needs to perform the actual count.

I will note that if you have an index on `persons(name)`, then the difference is minor -- in this case.  The index can be used for both queries.  Nevertheless, I advise you to use `exists`, because it better captures what you intend and it should have better performance.

Comment: I have a production database with 50K Johns so the difference might not be so minor :-)

Comment: @DanGuzman . . . With a unique index on `name`, the difference is actually minor (in this case) -- perhaps not even noticeable.  However, `count()` is a bad habit for this type of condition.

Comment: I didn't see that a unique index was mentioned. I agree the difference is negligible here.

Comment: IF EXISTS will take 2 steps i.e. Running Query and Evaluating If Condition and COUNT() will also take 3 steps i.e. Running Query, Performing Aggregation Operation and Evaluating If Condition. Can i add this prospective also?

Answer (score 0):

Exists is better. Exists will stop at the first matching row, Count will query all row matching where condition and compare